# Create new array or get old array values

Tags: php

```
class MY_CLASS {
    private $values;

    function __construct($new) {

        if($new == true) {
            //create new array
        } else {
            //show old elements
        }
        $this->values = array(
            //
        );
    }

    function get_value($i) {
        return $this->values[$i];
    }

}
```

I want to create an array of elements and a method for returning a particular value at a specified index but I want to get the same elements each time I call `get_value()` method via `AJAX` and the index will be incremented each time by one to get the array elemets one per call.

if `$new is true` new object (or array will be created) and if its false array will have the old elements.

```
$obj = new MY_CLASS($new);

echo $obj->get_value();
```

Is there a way to do this except `COOKIES`? Or is there a downside using COOKIES?

Comment: you use a session, which would use a cookie. cookies are client-side constructs, and you don't want to keep "operational" details in client-side systems.

Comment: What if is more than one page opened? They may update each other `SESSIONS`. @MarcB

Comment: then how do you propose to keep track of those separate pages using cookies? cookies are per-browser, not per-window. you'd have the EXACT same problem.

Comment: Yes you are right.// @MarcB I should find another solution